# Generic Database Save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

In my code I save a lot of classes to the database over and over using the same methodology. So I tried to abstract it, shown below:

```
public long Save<T>(BaseViewInterface<T> view, AppsRTSEntities dbContext)
{
    try
    {
        if (view.IsNew())
        {
            return Create(view, dbContext);
        }
        else
        {                
            T tmp = view.ToPersistent(dbContext);
            dbContext.T.Attach(tmp);
            dbContext.Entry(tmp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return tmp.ID;
        }
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException exc)
    {
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(GetExceptionMsg(exc), exc);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException exc)
    {
        throw new DbEntityValidationException(GetExceptionMsg(exc), exc);
    }
}
```

`T` is the autogenerated partial class Microsoft creates. So for instance my view would be

```
public class MyView : BaseViewInterface<My>
```

My would be the auto-generated class that is created as part of the db context. So my question is simple. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make this generic saving work?

Edit: I can't just modify `AppsRTSEntities` to include a definition for `T`, as it's also auto-generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intstead of doing `dbContext.T.Attach(tmp);` you need to use the [`DbContext.Set<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) method to get the generic `DbSet` datatype.

```
    else
    {                
        T tmp = view.ToPersistent(dbContext);
        //Could also do "dbCondext.Set<T>().Attach(tmp);"  but I split it for this example
        DbSet<T> t = dbCondext.Set<T>();
        t.Attach(tmp);
        dbContext.Entry(tmp).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return tmp.ID;
    }
```

Comment: It's saying that T must be a reference type. Any clue why Set<T>(); isn't working?

Comment: You need to add the constraint for it to be a class and not a struct. Change the function definition to `public long Save<T>(BaseViewInterface<T> view, AppsRTSEntities dbContext) where T : class` to add the constraint to the generic type.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! Last question, is there a way to get the id identifier with tmp being generic? Like a way to find that variable?

Comment: I believe `return (long)dbContext.Entry(tmp).CurrentValues["ID"];` may work. However a better solution is add a partial class to your generated types so that your types implment a interface called `IHasID` then have that interface be defined as `interface IHasID { long ID {get;} }` you can then change your constraint in your function to `where T : IHasID, class` then you could do `return tmp.ID;` without error. Using the `CurrentValues` method will give you a runtime error if you pass a T in without a `ID` property, using the interface method the code won't compile if you pass in a bad T.